# jquery Drag and Drop error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm having a problem with my code: its supposed to have draggabillity from right to left and should be sortable in the left. so far so good.
But im encountering an error: when i drag the items from the left div, another clone appears in the screen and i can't figure it out.
i also need help for adding multiple items from right and using a counter for showing the number of the same item.
here is my code:

```js
$(function drag() {
  $(".item").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '#droppable',
  });
});

$(function drop() {
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
  $("#droppable").sortable({
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $("#droppable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px black hidden;
  float: right;
}

.item {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 11.5%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  float: left;
}

#div_1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div_3 {
  background-color: black;
}

#div_4 {
  background-color: green;
}

#div_5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
  <div id="draggable">
    <div id="div_1" class="item red" draggable="true">1</div>
    <div id="div_2" class="item blue" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div id="div_3" class="item black" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div id="div_4" class="item green" draggable="true">4</div>
    <div id="div_5" class="item yellow" draggable="true">5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable" ondrop="drop(event)">
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: which `draggable` plugin are you using.?

Comment: im using the default jquery 1.5.0 draggable plugin.

Comment: did u check removing this `$("#droppable").sortable({helper: "clone"});`

Comment: yes i did at the beginning there was no sortable and the error was still there.

Comment: @Mamrez you have to use at least jquery 1.6 (otherwise it'll give you a script error on line 1 in the snippet).. when I run the snippet with 1.6, it says drop is not defined. That seems to the problem.. or one of them anyway

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks a lot that actually helped. so my code works so far.

Comment: @Mamrez happy to help. :)

Comment: @Mamrez is it your intention to be able to drag multiples of the same color from right to left?  if so, the accepted code doesn't work, cos you can drag many of the same color in it? Comment if you only want to drag one of each

Comment: @Mamrez i have an example of a sortable drag and drop in my fiddle library (no duplication) see this one https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/84gnzj4e/ and this one https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/y9Lb1ms8/ for examples

Comment: @RachelGallen actually i want multiple of the same item and a counter with the first part fixed, the rest is easy. thanks again

Comment: @Mamrez only just saw your comment. I see. just thought I could help. The fiddles may be helpful for future reference .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/0nf83chm/1/

```js
 $( ".item" ).draggable({
    cursor:'move',
    helper:'clone',
    appendTo:'#droppable',
 });


 $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.item',
    drop:function (event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
  });
  $("#droppable").sortable({helper: "clone"});
  $("#droppable").disableSelection();
```

```css
#draggable{width:150px; height:600px; border:1px black hidden; float:right;}
.item{width:70px; height:100px; border-radius:10%; margin:auto; margin-top:11.5%;}
.red{background-color:red;}
.blue{background-color:blue;}
.black{background-color:black;}
.green{background-color:green;}
.yellow{background-color:yellow;}
#droppable{width:150px; height:600px; border:1px black solid; float:left;}
#div_1{background-color:red;}
#div_2{background-color:blue;}
#div_3{background-color:black;}
#div_4{background-color:green;}
#div_5{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  <div id="div_1" class="item red" draggable="true">1</div>
  <div id="div_2" class="item blue" draggable="true">2</div>
  <div id="div_3" class="item black" draggable="true">3</div>
  <div id="div_4" class="item green" draggable="true">4</div>
  <div id="div_5" class="item yellow" draggable="true">5</div>
</div>
<div id="droppable" ></div>
```